# The Question of Vector space ,Subspace and their Base

Tags: vector-spaces

$V$ : Vector space ($\text{dim}V=n$)

$W_1, W_2$ : Subspace of $V$

$\text{dim}W_1 =1, \text{dim}W_2=2, W_1 \subset W_2$

If I let $\{ v_1 \}$ be basis of $W_1$, can I let $\{ v_1, v_2 \} \, (v_2 \in W_2)$ be basis of $W_2 $?

Answer (score 2):

That all depend on what $v_2$ is. If $v_2 = \lambda v_1$, $\{v_1,v_2\}$ won't be a basis of $W_2$. That will only work if $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as $v_2 \neq \alpha \cdot v_1, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{K}.$

If $v_2 = \alpha \cdot v_1$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{K},$ then $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is not linearly independent, and it can’t be a base.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can choose a basis of $W_2$ that contains the vector $v_1$. This is due to the assumption that $W_1$ is a subspace of $W_2$.